# Socket IO and Dynamic Rooms

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

If anyone is experienced with Websockets / Socket IO hopefully you can point me in the right direction.

I made a Discord Clone and I'm trying to optimize it to scale better. Right now when a user sends a message I query the DB for all users part of that server, and emit a message to their specific socket. This is obviously not going to scale well as every message requires a expensive query and lookup in the client list

```
// Emit messages to only users part of specific server
    // Will only return list of users part of server and active in last 10 minutes
    sqlQuery = `SELECT userservers.user_id FROM userservers 
                  JOIN users ON users.user_id = userservers.user_id AND users.user_last_active > (NOW() - INTERVAL 10 minute)
                  WHERE server_id = ${sql.escape(serverId)}`;
    const users = await sql.query(sqlQuery);
    action = { type: "message", payload: msg };

    // Iterate over users, and find them in clients list
    // Emit over socket only to that user
    users.forEach((user) => {
      clients.forEach((client) => {
        if (client.userId === user.user_id) {
          io.to(client.id).emit(user.user_id, action);
        }
      })
    });
```

However using Rooms for each Sever would eliminate my need to query the DB. I understand I can do this when the socket server first starts

```
// Get server list from Mysql DB
servers.forEach((server) => {
    socket.join(server.name);
}
```

However my issue becomes, when a user create a new server once the application is already running It will not update the list.

I am probably missing some concept on creating dynamic rooms.

EDIT : I am thinking the solution could be that every time a "server" is created, I send a message to the socket server so it can join that "room"

Answer (score 1):

> Right now when a user sends a message I query the DB for all users part of that server

I think you can submit broad cast message to all online users, so instead of `forEach client => io.to(clientId)`  you can submit broad cast message to all connected users `io.emit('some event', { for: 'everyone' });`

also I'm wondering why you are creating many servers? you can divide your server into namespaces by using `const namespace = io.of('/thisIsASeparateNamespace');` and also you can submit broadcast messages to all users inside this name space by `namespace.emit('some event', { for: 'everyone in name space' });`

So your chat structure can be like this

Server

- Namespaces // for separate chat app / or like slack work spaces
- Rooms // for group chatting
- ClientID // for one to one

Comment: It's exactly like Discord, any user can create a server and channels within it. Not sure if I'm understanding your approach but I'll give it a second thought

Comment: I would like to know why you are querying users table for each public message to a specific server,and you can just call `server.emit(...)`, please check [this](https://socket.io/get-started/chat/#Broadcasting)

Comment: That is the goal. My question was related to how to do socket.join on new servers added to the database, without needed to listen to changes in the database. Read the end of my post might be a more clear to what my original question was.